# Problem with audio sharing between different programs

Tags: sound

I've been using Linux for quite some time, but until now I've never run into any problems. I also saw the thread "Sound, stopping between multiple programs", but it is referring to a very old version...

My problem is that when I run Diablo 3 (using PlayOnLinux) and Skype 4 at the same time, I only get audio from the program that I start first.

If I start skype first and then Diablo 3, I have perfekt audio in Skype and sometimes I might hear a faint whisper of the Diablo sounds...

This problem started after I changed motherboard to Asus p8z77-v pro with 16GB memory and Intel i7 3770K CPU. With the old motherboard, all this worked just fine.
The OS is Ubuntu 12.04.
I have only installed Wine, PlayOnLinux, Skype 4, and Diablo 3. All of the latest version, as far as I know.

What should I do?
What do you need to know, in order to be able to help?

Thanks
/Lasse

Comment: I've tried to use other sound sources at the same time. Nothing works the way it did with my old motherboard. It is always the first started program that is able to produce sound.

Comment: What I also noticed was that when Skype is the second program and therefore can't produce sound, it takes a lot longer to startup, like it is trying to find a reference to something, but times out.

Answer (score 0):

Not a solution, but the problem is likely related to the fact that Wine bypasses the `pulseaudio` mixer used by most sound applications (including recent versions of `skype`, AFAIK), and interfaces directly with the [lower level `ALSA` sound driver](http://wiki.winehq.org/Sound). It *should* be possible to make `ALSA` handle multiple clients, but since everything in Ubuntu is *meant* to go through `pulseaudio` first I imagine this is not configured.